# No connection to port 8333 in VMware server on Linux

Tags: linux, vmware-server

I have installed a headless VMware server on my Linux Debian server.

For some reason I cannot connect to the web management console on port 8333. However, if I port forward localhost via ssh to the remote server (and set Firefox up to use the proxy), I can connect to the management console without problems. Using this approach I have succesfully started the virtual machine.

I can also telnet to vmware server on port 8333 when logged in on the remote server.

When I run a **vmware status** command, I see this message among others:

```
Host network detection is not running
```

I am not sure if this has something to do with the problem, though.

I have tried both

```
/etc/init.d/vmware-mgmt restart
```

and

```
/etc/init.d/vmware restart
```

but that doesn't make any difference.

As far as I know, there is no firewall on the server, but to be honest I am not completely sure how to check this!

Thanks in advance for any hints that might help me solve the problem :)

EDIT:

This is the result of netstat:

```
netstat -anp | grep :8333
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8333            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12850/vmware-hostd
```

Comment: I have removed your VMware tag as VMware is a company who make a number of virtualization products. Please consider adding a product specific tag which can be found as **vmware**-*product*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I didn't know was the host company had a hardware firewall which had to be opened as well. I only checked the local iptables rules. Now it works correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try stopping the services, running a `ps aux` and grepping for `vm to make sure all of the processes died, then starting the daemons again? Also, are you using https to connect to the web console?

Comment: I just tried now to no avail. And yes, I am using https.